# Extracting a value from a certain location in a .csv file

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which contains a column of paths to a number of csvs `df['path']`. The csv look like below:

```
# Reaction: a +  94Mo Production of  94Ru Ground state
# Beam current:      0.00250 mA Energy range:   40.000 -->   39.000 MeV
# Irradiation time     :      0 years   0 days  5 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds 
# Cooling time         :      0 years   0 days  0 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds 
# Half life            :      0 years   0 days  0 hours 51 minutes 48 seconds 
# Maximum production at:      0 years   0 days 20 hours 50 minutes 10 seconds 
# Initial production rate:  1.87357E-14 [s^-1] Decay rate:  2.23020E-04 [s^-1]
# # time points =100
# Time [h] Activity [GBq] #isotopes [   ]  Yield [GBq/mAh]  Isotopic frac.
     0.1    9.06448E-05    4.06442E+08    3.62579E-01        0.00355
     0.2    1.74297E-04    7.81528E+08    3.34607E-01        0.00347
     0.3    2.51495E-04    1.12768E+09    3.08792E-01        0.00339
```

I'm looking to extract the value of 'half-life'. In everyfile this is always the number on the fifth row of the .csv file, after the colon.

**Answered:**
From the answer below I constructed a regex to extract the value:

```
for i, p in enumerate(df['path']):
    with open(p, 'r') as f:
            text = open(p)
            for line in text:
                if re.match('# Half life\s*:\s*([^\n]+)', line):
                    number = re.match('# Half life\s*:\s*([^\n]+)', line).group(1)
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `# Half life\s*:\s*([^\n]+)`?

Comment: So did you tried something?

Comment: @dvo Yes, this is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Allentro posted as answer with explanation on the different pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern should work for you.

`# Half life\s*:\s*([^\n]+)`

---

It matches the start of the string: `# Half life`

Then, the variable number of spaces to the colon: `\s*:`

Then, another variable number of spaces: `\s*`

Then, it *captures* everything up until a new line character: `([^\n]+)`

You can access the value in capture group 1.